# The drop-down list XXX vs. the XXX drop-down list. Are there any rules for determining which to use?

Tags: word-order, syntax, terminology

Are there defined rules anywhere concerning whether a UI element type (e.g. drop-down list) comes before or after its name (e.g. Install)? A few examples:

> 1. the drop-down list **Install** vs. the **Install** drop-down list
> 2. the table **MATNR** vs. the **MATNR** table
> 3. the option **Copy existing content to target table** vs. the **Copy existing
>      content to target table** option
> 4. the options **Copy content**, **Save content** and **Delete content** vs. the **Copy
>      content**, **Save content** and **Delete content** options

The same would apply to words like “parameter”, “window”, “tab” and “chapter”.

Does the length of the name affect this rule? E.g. Something like “if more than four words, write the name before the UI element”. (example 3)

Or whether multiple UI elements are described as opposed to just one? (example 4)

Or whether the UI element type functions as a noun or an adjective?

Comment: When the name follows the noun, we tend to drop the article:  *The records are found in [] table CUST.*   *The records are stored in the CUST table.*

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I would always use the **name** before the *thing*. I'm sure if you read enough technical manuals you will notice this.

> **Install** dropdown

since otherwise it would be

> the dropdown for **Install**

this way the *name* is the *adjective* for the *object*.

> the **MATR** table
>   the **Copy existing content to target table** option
>   the **Copy content, Save content and Delete content** options

although in the last example

> the options ***for*** **Copying, Saving and Deleting** content.

might be preferable, depending on usage.

As with all *technical writing*, it is important to be consistent since these are instructions and not a story.

Comment: Thanks Peter. In #4, those are the exact button names in the GUI, so I have to keep them as is. So a long description like "Copy existing content to target table" still functions as an adjective? Even if it were to contain 10+ words? I know that 10+ words should be avoided, but I often can't change what is written in the software.

Comment: Unfortunate that you can't change the wording since "***Copy To Table***" would suffice (obviously, you can only copy **existing content** and the table would be the **target**).  For the documentation to be as clear as possible, it's usually best to quote labels and buttons exactly as they appear.